# Поддержка оффлайн работы сайта

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

Здравствуйте. Вчера нашел библиотеку на js, называется **upup**, с помощью её можно отображать страницы сайта когда подключение к интернету пропало.

Как сказано в [официальной документации](https://www.talater.com/upup/), все что нужно, это подключить библиотеку и вывести то что нам нужно. (Это может быть страница, или просто надпись).

Как я сделал:

Перед закрытием `</body>` вставил `<script src="upup.min.js"></script>`, в документации сказано, чтобы библиотека была в корне нашего сайта а не в дочерней папке.

Дальше написал простую фразу, которую должно показывать при потере соеденения:

```
<script>
UpUp.start({ content: 'Cannot reach site. Please check your internet connection.' });
</script>
```

По сути должно было работать, но не работает. По прежнему показывает ошибку браузера, хотя на сайте **upup** такое работает, можете [перейти на сайт](https://www.talater.com/upup/) и отключить интернет.

Comment: service worker зарегистрирован, проверяли?

Comment: @dakiesse, только что прочитал подробнее об этом, и насколько я понял, нужно иметь SSL сертификат для того чтобы использовать это, правильно?

Comment: все верно, а бесплатный ssl можно получить на https://www.cloudflare.com/ , а вот статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/239507/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы service worker необходимо чтобы у сайта был SSL сертификат.